# git blame-like annotation of source files with gcov

Tags: c, gcov

I have successfully set up gcov in my project to generate HTML files with code coverage data using `lcov`. However, as I often work via SSH with a text console only, I'm looking for a way to generate annotated source files like `git-blame` does with the history:

```
covered     source_line();
not covered other_source_line();
```

Is it possible somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume you are referring to `gcovr` when you say `gcov`, since `gcov` does not output to HTML format. `gcovr` does output to HTML though. `gcovr` is basically just a wrapper for `gcov`.

**In order to get the annotated source files, you need to simply use `gcov`.**

`gcov`, by default, annotates source files.

To run with gcov, you just need to compile with `-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -fPIC -O0`, and link in the gcov library(`-lgcov`).

Then run your program.

Then issue the following command:

```
gcov main.c
```

Where `main.c` is whatever file you want your annotated analysis on.

After that, you will notice a new file created(main.c.gcov). This is the file you are looking for.

[Here's](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-Gcov.html#Invoking-Gcov) a link on `gcov` usage

Comment: No, I forgot to mention that HTML is generated by lcov, not gcov. These `.gcov` files are a bit cryptic, with lots of lines like `123. /* EOF */` I take a look into them, I guess this is what `lcov` parses, and maybe I can create the desired output from it.

Comment: That's correct. lcov just uses those .gcov files to create nice html pages. gcov is definitely what you're looking for. It might take some tweaking with the options. It is all documented in the gcov link I gave

Comment: Also, the lcov is very nice to have. Why don't  you just copy the html files back to your computer via scp, and view the files with a web browser?

Comment: Because of mobile bandwidth limitations :) I’m having fun with gcov now, I will publish the results somewhere soon(ish).

Comment: Turns out all I needed was `gcov -a main.c` It generates just the output I need.